# Need help creating something like this moving image slideshow thing

Tags: html, css, slideshow

[Example of the moving image (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03u8a.png)
I've been trying to make this moving slideshow for the past couple of week and I just can't seem to crack it. I'm still new to html and css so I just don't know what else to try. The one in the picture fades in when you open the website and continuously moves like a carousel, I just can't seem to figure it out. I want mine to look like the one in the picture.

This is what I have, but it's not the same and I don't really like it or know how to make it appear as the one in the picture

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 510px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.slider-frame {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}


/*---------- SLIDE ANIMATION --------------*/

@keyframes slide_animation {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  10% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 2400px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 2400px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  90% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide_animation {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  10% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 2400px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 2400px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 1200px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  90% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

.slide-images {
  width: 3600px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2400px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide_animation;
  animation-name: slide_animation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 33s;
  animation-duration: 33s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.img-container {
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="slider-frame">
  <div class="slide-images">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/48/44/knh76C.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/4250656.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://preview.redd.it/38aeu51hq3d61.jpg?auto=webp&s=ae0c88bc1b22516c312823c697e44285e961f748">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know you're a begineer and trying to make something from your own is good but there are so many library present to get the carousel effect https://niemvuilaptrinh.medium.com/28-carousel-slider-library-for-developer-a213d20b1293

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? Make it look like the one in the picture? What does that mean? Your carousel seems to be working already.